# Unity freezes when running BFS update instead of visualizing each step

Tags: unity, c#

I made a visualization of Breadth First Search in Unity. It consists of an area of square planes which will change color as they are visited.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BFS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject blockArea;
    (int, int)[] moves = new (int, int)[4] { (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1) };

    public void bfs()
    {
        List<(int, int)> starts = new List<(int, int)>();
        List<(int, int)> goals = new List<(int, int)>();

        GameObject[][] blocks = blockArea.GetComponent<Area>().area;
        int[][] area = new int[blocks.Length + 2][];

        for (int i = 0; i < area.Length; i++)
        {
            area[i] = new int[blocks[0].Length + 2];
            for (int j = 0; j < area[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == area.Length - 1 || j == area[i].Length - 1)
                {
                    area[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    area[i][j] = blocks[i - 1][j - 1].GetComponent<Block>().state;
                    if (area[i][j] == 2)
                    {
                        starts.Add((i, j));
                    }
                    else if (area[i][j] == 3)
                    {
                        goals.Add((i, j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ExecuteBFS(ref area, ref blocks, ref starts, ref goals);
    }

    (int, int) AddTuple((int, int) first, (int, int) second)
    {
        return (first.Item1 + second.Item1, first.Item2 + second.Item2);
    }

    void ExecuteBFS(ref int[][] area, ref GameObject[][] blocks, ref List<(int, int)> starts, ref List<(int, int)> goals)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < starts.Count; s++)
        {
            Queue<(int, int)> q = new Queue<(int, int)>();
            q.Enqueue(starts[s]);

            while (q.Count != 0 && q.Peek() != goals[0])
            {
                (int, int) cor = q.Dequeue();

                for (int i = 0; i < moves.Length; i++)
                {
                    (int, int) newCor = AddTuple(cor, moves[i]);
                    if (area[newCor.Item1][newCor.Item2] == 3)
                    {
                        //showPath
                        goals.Remove(newCor);
                        if (goals.Count == 0)
                        {
                            //stats
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (area[newCor.Item1][newCor.Item2] == 0)
                    {
                        //coordinate in process
                        blocks[newCor.Item1 - 1][newCor.Item2 - 1].GetComponent<Block>().SetState(5);
                        area[newCor.Item1][newCor.Item2] = 5;

                        q.Enqueue(newCor);

                        //delay
                        MyDelay(0.01f);
                        //coordinate visited
                        blocks[newCor.Item1 - 1][newCor.Item2 - 1].GetComponent<Block>().SetState(4);
                        area[newCor.Item1][newCor.Item2] = 4;
                    }
                }
            }
            //stats
        }
    }

    public static void MyDelay(float seconds)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

        do { } while (DateTime.Now < dt);
    }
```

This is my Block script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Block : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] materials;
    //0 - empty
    //1 - wall
    //2 - start
    //3 - goal
    //4 - visited
    //5 - current
    public int state;

    void Start()
    {
        state = 0;
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[state];
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        SetState(Area.selectedState);
    }

    public void SetState(int s)
    {
        state = s;
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[state];
    }
}
```

When I start the BFS search, the whole Unity editor freezes. After some time depending on the delay argument, it starts responding and the visited planes are all colored. But it won't color them one by one as they are visited.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I don't see you are using Coroutines for that. Try searching Coroutines topic.
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/unity-c-sharp-scripting-beyond-basics/table-of-contents
Is a nice course.

Comment: If you want to see your code running step by step, like pausing execution till next frame or 100ms, put your code in a Coroutine and yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f); instead of your delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is written under the assumption that the player can see directly into the memory of the program as it's running. So as long as you change a variable, the player should be able to immediately observe that change, like if you'd flipped a physical card on the table in front of them.

Games don't work that way. If we want a player to see something change in our world, we need to draw it to an image and put that image on the player's screen first. That takes some work from the CPU to initiate. And the CPU can't do that work if it's busy doing something else.

A typical game loop looks something like this, in a simplified model:

1. Process window messages - this is what keeps the application from hanging, and allows it to read user input provided from the OS
2. Update the game state, running any per-object update scripts
3. Render the resulting frame and present it to the screen
4. Sleep until it's time for the next frame

This most often runs single-threaded, and that's the case for the Unity game loop too. (Even systems that use threading typically use it to "go wide" in a single step, like running multiple non-conflicting state updates in parallel in step 2, while still finishing all step 2 work before taking a state snapshot to render in step 3)

So, as long as you're keeping the CPU busy in step 2, it never gets to step 3, so you never get to see an intermediate state rendered. And it also never gets back to step 1, which is what makes the app go unresponsive until your script finishes its work.

The culprit is your `MyDelay` function:

```
public static void MyDelay(float seconds)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
    do { } while (DateTime.Now < dt);
}
```

This is what's called a "Busy Wait" - it tells the CPU to sit there checking and re-checking the time, burning millions of cycles doing nothing useful at all, until it's allowed to continue on to the next line of code. You've temporarily suspended any real processing and turned this CPU core into a space heater.

(There are times when a busy wait is appropriate, when you think you'll very likely be waiting less time than it takes to sleep and wake a thread. A busy loop running for a hundredth of a second as you have here is *never* a good idea, and you should throw away any tutorial that told you to do that)

Because you've kept this thread busy this whole time, it's not allowed to exit step 2 and continue on to step 3, rendering your changes for the player to see them, until the whole routine has finished. At that point it shows only the finished state.

The better way to do something like this in Unity is to use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). This is a function that can run *partially*, then `yield` control flow back to the code that called it, so the CPU can finish the rest of step 2 and draw it in step 3. Then, in the next iteration of the game loop, the calling code can resume your coroutine right where it left off, and continue until the next `yield`. In this way it takes turns with all the other work needed to update and render your scene, rather than hogging the CPU to itself until it's finished.

Here's an example of what that could look like. Along the way I also cleaned up some issues:

- Used a descriptive enumeration instead of magic numbers to define the different tile states
- Swapped empty and wall so we get the border around the map for free from default initialization
- Used the built-in `Vector2Int` type instead of a tuple that needs a new add method defined
- Reduced the number of temporary collections allocated during the search

```
public class BFS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TileState {        
        Wall,
        Empty,
        Start,
        Goal,
        Visited,
        Current
    }

    static readonly Vector2Int[] MOVES = new Vector2Int[] {
        Vector2Int.right, Vector2Int.up, Vector2Int.left, Vector2Int.down
    };

    public float delayPerStep = 0.01f;

    TileState[,] InitializeSearchSpace(Block[,] blocks, Queue<Vector2Int> startingPoints, out int goalCount) {
        goalCount = 0;

        int width = blocks.GetLength(0);
        int height = blocks.GetLength(1);
        TileState[,] area = new TileState[width + 2, height + 2];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
                TileState state = blocks[x, y].GetState();
                switch (state) {
                    case TileState.Start:
                        startingPoints.Enqueue(new Vector2Int(x + 1, y + 1));
                        break;
                    case TileState.Goal:
                        goalCount++;
                        break;
                }
                area[x + 1, y + 1] = state;
            }
        }

        return area;
    }

    IEnumerator RunSearch(Block[,] blocks, TileState[,] area, Queue<Vector2Int> openSet, int goalsRemaining) {

        float timeBudget = Time.deltaTime;

        while (openSet.Count > 0 && goalsRemaining > 0) {
            var tile = openSet.Dequeue();

            foreach(var move in MOVES) {
                var next = tile + move;
                switch(area[next.x, next.y]) {
                    case TileState.Wall:
                    case TileState.Visited:
                        continue;                    
                    case TileState.Goal:
                        goalsRemaining--;
                        break;
                }
                blocks[next.x - 1, next.y - 1].SetState(TileState.Current);

                timeBudget -= delayPerStep;
                while (timeBudget <= 0f) {
                     yield return null;
                     timeBudget += Time.deltaTime;
                }

                blocks[next.x - 1, next.y - 1].SetState(TileState.Visited);
                area[next.x, next.y] = TileState.Visited;

                openSet.Enqueue(next);
            }
        }
    }

    public void BreadthFirstSearch(Block[,] blocks) {
        var openSet = new Queue<Vector2Int>();

        var area = InitializeSearchSpace(blocks, openSet, out int goalCount);

        StartCoroutine(RunSearch(blocks, area, openSet, goalCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours answers and explanation! Yeah I had coroutines there before but with the same result. But now I divided my code to initialization of the BFS search and then to ExecuteOneStepOfBFS() and I am checking in Update() if BFS was started and if yes, execute one step and yield for some time, it works now. I dont know if this is the best approach though.

Comment: We'd need to see your coroutine implementation to help you debug it. I've got a partial rewrite of this code in terms of coroutines and fixing some other problems (eg. why create your own tuple add function when `Vector2Int` exists), but I'll need a bit more time to finish it before I can add it to this answer.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to set the delay to e.g. 0,01 seconds? In bigger maps and mazes, so the algorithm wouldnt be instant but still faster than half second each step. I think I cant achieve it with coroutines as WaitForSeconds(0.01f) an WaitForSeconds(0.0001f) makes no difference;

Comment: Of course it doesn't, because the soonest that `WaitForSeconds` can resume is next frame - usually more like 16.7 ms. You can solve this trivially - just keep track of how much time budget you have to spend, and decrease it by your delay duration for each step. Once you go into time debt, yield for a frame, and use the time that passed to increase your budget. I've edited the answer above to show this.